# Vue component prop change does not trigger rerender

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

In my Vue 2 application I have a big object that is passed from the root component down several levels to some child components as a prop. When I change some property of the object the child components should update and rerender. In some cases they do, in other cases they don't. I need some help spotting why it does not work.

Here is a child component, which does not update:

```
<template>
<div class="upgradeBar">
    {{level}}
    <div
            v-for="lvlNum in maxLevel + 1"
            class="level"
            v-bind:class="{reached: isLevelReached(lvlNum - 1)}"
    ></div>

    <button
            class="btnUpgrade"
            @click="onLevelUp()"
            v-if="!isLevelReached(maxLevel)"
    >
        +
    </button>
</div>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
import {Component, Prop, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Upgradable from "../../../models/Upgradable";

@Component()
export default class UpgradeBar extends Vue {
    name: 'UpgradeBar';

    @Prop() entity: Upgradable;

    get level(): number {
        return this.entity.level;
    }

    get maxLevel(): number {
        return this.entity.MAX_LEVEL;
    }

    onLevelUp() {
        this.entity.levelUp();
    }

    isLevelReached(level: number): Boolean {
        return this.entity.level >= level;
    }
}
</script>
```

The component is called like this:

```
<UpgradeBar :entity="entity" />
```

All the code works. When I click the `btnUpgrade` button entity.level is indeed changed, but I need to close and reopen the component to see the changes. Also the browser dev tool does not show the change instantly. I need to click on the component to refresh the values in the debugger.

EDIT:
The `entity` class looks basicly like this (excerpt):

```
class Entity {
    name: string = 'some name';
    level: number = 1;
}
```

I searched deeper and it seems to boils down to this: Some properties of the object are reactive (they have getters / setters created by vue) and some don't. `entity.name` has a setter, so changing it updates the component. `entity.level` does not. Here's the question: Why are they treated differently? Here is a log:

[image: console.log of entity]

Comment: Added the Entity class. Adding `{{entity.level}}` or `{{entity._level}}` to the template does not help.

Comment: this pattern of using models (with internal state and functionality) is not very common in Vue. I'm not sure if passing classes as props will have some unexpected issues.

Comment: Apperently it has unexpected issues, although it works quite well in other places :) What would you suggest? Pass simple values as props?

Comment: my suggestion would be to use Vuex (flux pattern, a single store management) you would essentially have a single place for all data (like an internal noSQL document store) Then instead of passing instances of objects around, you manage a single instance from anywhere using globally accessible functions(actions/getters). It will be easier to debug, for example, it gives you a way to step through the state history. However, you'll still need to use `Vue.$set`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can't tell for sure without seeing the code for `entity.levelUp`, but it seems like a reactivity issue, that may be solved by using `Vue.$set` inside that function.

You can confirm this being the case by adding `this.$forceUpdate();`  after `this.entity.levelUp();`

**update**

`this._level = this._level + 1;`

can be changed to

`Vue.$set(this, _level, this._level + 1);`
You will need to import Vue in that component/file to access the $set function

Comment: The `this.$forceUpdate();` indeed helps. So how do I need to change the code to make the forceUpdate unnecessary?

Comment: you should remove the forceUpdate to test. Leaving forceUpdate in can impact performance, as it does a full check for all obects instead of using reactivity to selectively update. It's worth reading over this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html (I've read it multiple times before understanding)

Comment: So yes, it is a reactivity problem. I added a `console.log` of the object. Very few properties are reactive. `name` is one of them. `level` is not although it is handled exaclty the same. How can that be?

Comment: how would it be for vue 3?

Comment: @brauliobo in short, it depends. If you're using a `ref` you could use a `set` function. Gets more complicated with a reactive.

Answer (score 5):

You don't show (or I can't find) the code that changes the object, but are you using `$set()` or `Vue.set()` instead of simply changing the object's properties directly? Changing a property directly generally doesn't work because of [reactivity limitations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

---

Edited to add:

I see now. I think you want something like:

```
this.$set(this, '_level', this._level + 1);
```